# X-Geo HTTP Header

Tags: iis, http-headers

Does anyone know the specs for the `X-GEO` HTTP header?  I am seeing some in my logs, and looked for a spec or something, but didn't find anything that explains the values I am seeing. Any reference to the header I find online show values like `US` etc. e.g.

> Here is part of packet:
>
> ```
> X-Geo: US
> X-Real-IP: 54.83.132.159
> ```

Source: https://distinctplace.com/2014/04/23/story-behind-x-forwarded-for-and-x-real-ip-headers/

...But there is no explanation of that particular header.

The ones I see seem to be encoded but I am not sure of the format. Here is a sample of some of the values I am seeing. All of them follow this similar format:

```
a cm9sZToxIHByb2R1Y2VyOjEyIHRpbWVzdGFtcDoxNDY4NjQwMjIyNTcxMDAwIGxhdGxuZ3tsYXRpdHVkZV9lNzo0MTY5ODkzOTQgbG9uZ2l0dWRlX2U3Oi03Mzg5NjYyMTB9IHJhZGl1czoxOTc2NA==
```

Is there any info behind this type of value if decoded? Anyone know there the spec for the `x-Geo` header might live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cm9sZToxIHByb2R1Y2VyOjEyIHRpbWVzdGFtcDoxNDY4NjQwMjIyNTcxMDAwIGxhdGxuZ3tsYXRpdHVkZV9lNzo0MTY5ODkzOTQgbG9uZ2l0dWRlX2U3Oi03Mzg5NjYyMTB9IHJhZGl1czoxOTc2NA==` string is Base64.

It decodes as `role:1 producer:12 timestamp:1468640222571000 latlng{latitude_e7:416989394 longitude_e7:-738966210} radius:19764`.

Comment: Thanks. Still looking for reference to the docs for this one, if anyone knows of one.

Answer (score 1):

Adding info on the spec, etc.

Code for this header is found in the Google Chromium source code for the Omnibox:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/omnibox/geo/GeolocationHeader.java

The code in the `GeolocationHeader.java` file above gives an insight somewhat.

Some relevent comments from within that:

```
/**
 * Provides methods for building the X-Geo HTTP header, which provides device location to a server
 * when making an HTTP request.
 *
 * X-Geo header spec: https://goto.google.com/xgeospec.
 */
```

I can't access that `https://goto.google.com/xgeospec` document url though... `Access not possible` any ideas? Looks like it can only be accessed by someone with a google.com email address.

Comment: For what it's worth, `goto.google.com` is Google's internal URL shortener. The author of that comment probably forgot that their comment might be read by non-Google employees.

Comment: Any googlers who might be able to get the target URI behind the shortened URL? :)